# Create Object by using Lambda Expression based on Class Name

Tags: vb.net, reflection, lambda, expression

I refer to the link below:

```
http://rogeralsing.com/2008/02/28/linq-expressions-creating-objects/
```

Is it possible to enhance it to create object by providing the class name? 
Basically to achieve what Activator.CreateInstance could do below by using Lambda Expression

```
Dim typeName As String = "Testing.ClassNameth, Testing"
Dim typ As Type = Type.GetType(typeName)
Dim testObj = Activator.CreateInstance(typ)
Dim methodInfo As MethodInfo = testObj.GetType().GetMethod("TestPrintObject")
```

The purpose on why I am doing it is because the Activator.CreateInstance's performance is quite slow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After few researches, below is the answer:
Add the functions below to any of your related class:

```
Public Function GetActivator(Of T)(type As Type) As ObjectActivator(Of T)
    'make a NewExpression that calls the
    'ctor with the args we just created
    Dim newExp As NewExpression = Expression.[New](type)

    'create a lambda with the New
    'Expression as body
    Dim lambda As LambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(GetType(ObjectActivator(Of T)), newExp)

    'compile it
    Dim compiled As ObjectActivator(Of T) = DirectCast(lambda.Compile(), ObjectActivator(Of T))
    Return compiled
End Function

 Public Delegate Function ObjectActivator(Of T)() As T
```

Then we can call the function above as:

```
Dim typeName As String = "Testing.ClassNameth, Testing"
Dim typ As Type = Type.GetType(typeName)
Dim testObj As Object = YourHelperClassInstance.GetActivator(Of Object)(typ).Invoke()
```

Hope this post would help someone in the future.

Thanks!